# Sightly (HTL) List iteration

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

How do I iterate over an arrayList of String values in Sightly?

Using my backend java class I get an ArrayList returned to Sightly. How do I iterate over and display them?

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `data-sly-list` or `data-sly-repeat` to iterate over collections / iterables in HTL. Both of them work the same with the only difference, `data-sly-repeat` doesn't require a container whereas `data-sly-list` requires one.

Usage:

Method 1

```
<ul data-sly-list="${someList}">
    <li>${item}</li>
</ul>
```

Method 2

```
<ul>
    <li data-sly-repeat="${someList}">${item}</li>
</ul>
```

Both of which produces the same output as shown below

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

More about the [HTL Block Statements can be found here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#227-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `data-sly-list` ?

Example:

```
<ul data-sly-list.myitem="${mylist}" data-sly-unwrap>
  <li>${myitem}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to check if mylist is empty?

Answer (score -1):

data-sly-list use the container such as  Please see the example for the better understanding.

I have below List

```
test1
test2
test3
test4

<div data-sly-list="${ currentPage.listChildren }">
      ${item.name}
</div>
```

Output will be generated as –

```
test1 test2 test3 test4
```

And when you view the HTML element structure in you debugger then it will be –

```
<div>
   Test1
   Test2
   Test3
   Test4
<div>
```

Now use data-sly-repeat–

```
<div data-sly-repeat="${ currentPage.listChildren }">
      ${item.name}
</div>
```

Output will be –
    XHTML

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```